# How to add the distrubtion group in Active Directory for a user?

Tags: windows, programming-languages, powershell, active-directory, activedirectorymembership

How to add the distrubtion group from Powershell in Active Directory ?

I have user in active directory and i want to add the user into particular group rather than going and server because that part is going to be outsourced.

so how to add the distrubution group for particular user.

Comment: You should really try more when asking a question. Bad title, very short question, no info about what you have tried so far...

Comment: You never answered my question :@stej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basic code:

$group = [adsi]"LDAP://CN=Group1,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=com"
$group.member.Add('CN=User1,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com')
$group.SetInfo()

Answer (score 0):

'Add-ADGroupMember' is useful here if you have ActiveDirectory module available.  Powershell 3.0 and later have it available by default.  Use Get-Help for syntax.